# Monitoring IP phones with Zenoss 3.0 Core

Tags: monitoring, cisco, zenoss

I have the following situation. I have some IP phones configured and registered in to a CCM in the lab. I have already enabled the SNMP service in CCM and I'm able to make a SNMP walk using a linux shell (the community and the version are OK). I would like to monitor the amount of IP phones that are registered/unregistered using Zenoss.

The CCM OID for those request are the following:

```
ccmRegisteredPhones   : 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.156.1.5.5.0
ccmUnregisteredPhones : 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.156.1.5.6.0
```

I'm able to get the value (number of registered and unregistered phones in the server) using the smnpwalk in the command line.
Everything works 'till now, but I would like to monitor those values using Zenoss and make an alarm wheter the amount of unregistered phones is below a value.

I would like to know the steps I have to follow in Zenoss 3.0 Core to get those request working/monitoring since I can't get anything clear from the Zenos UserGuide.

I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new monitoring template called "CCMPhones" or something like that. Add two SNMP datasources to this monitoring template. The convention would be to name them after the OIDs: ccmRegisteredPhones and ccmUnregisteredPhones. Put the appropriate OIDs from your question as the OIDs for these datasources.

You can then add these to a graph and create thresholds for them if desired.

At this point you have the monitoring ready to go, but it isn't being applied to any devices. I would recommend creating a device class for your CCM devices. If they're Linux-based you'd create /Server/Linux/CCM and place your CCM devices there. Then in that device class you can click over to More and choose "Bind Templates" from the gear menu in the bottom left. Select your CCMPhones template.

Now any devices you put into the /Server/Linux/CCM device class will have the CCMPhones monitoring applied to them.